# InDesign CS5 tables: Can I automatically fit rows or columns to the size of content?

Tags: adobe-indesign

You know how Excel has the function "Autofit," where you select a whole row or a whole column and it resizes the entire thing to the height or depth of the largest content item? I want to do that in an InDesign table, but with one click. (I know I can drag the column out until the overflow box goes away, but I want to know if there's some automated function I'm overlooking.) Does this automatic function exist anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InDesign will happily expand the vertical dimension of a row (use the "At Least" setting for row height in the `Tables > Cell Options > Rows & Columns` dialog). Horizontal (column) autofit isn't built in, and off-hand I don't know of a plug-in that supports this, either. [Pause] Couldn't find one after searching InDesign Secrets or the usual plug-in suspects, either.

There are good reasons why the column width autofit isn't implemented, of course, but there's no reason not to put in a feature request for it. If enough people ask, it will bubble up in the priority list for the engineering team to work on. Chris Kitchener (the InDesign Product Manager) is very responsive to requests.

Comment: good idea! I will look into that.

Comment: By the way, there is an excellent series of videos by Michael Murphy on the subject of tables in InDesign. On his blog (www.theindesigner.com) or via podcast.

Answer (score 1):

This [Tables_2_Frame](http://github.com/GitBruno/Novelty/blob/master/Tables_2_Frame.jsx) script fits the the table to the containing textframe and auto grows the cells to fit content. You could adjust the script by setting `autogrow` to `false` and adjusting the `Column.width` until `Column.overflows` returns `true`.