# Indesign auto column width size for table based on the data containing?

Tags: adobe-indesign, information-design, indesign-scripting

I have a lot of tables that designers have to adjust slightly to fit the content. This takes a large amount of time in our process and I would like to know if there is anyway to skip this? Perhaps a custom script?

If not, could you suggest what I should do? How would I go about creating my own script to auto-fit the columns to the data?

*Also the table must always be 100% of the available width (normally into a text-box)*

Comment: Not that I'm aware of within InDesign but I've seen a [thread on Adobe forums](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform) linking to [a book on InDesign scripting](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596802530.do) that *apparently* includes a script that does this. I have no idea if it actually works, if there's a better place to find the script, if it still works in CS6, etc - but that might help.

Comment: Oops looks like I posted the wrong link above: the adobe forums link should have been http://forums.adobe.com/message/2280922  also, this question should be linked to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4235/ (which sadly doesn't have an answer either)

Comment: Can you throw up some images explaining what you're looking to do?

Comment: Now I can't, but imagine you throw a lot of data in excel and then select the columns and then double click on them. It will resize the columns to fit the data.

Answer (score 1):

If the table width must stay the same the only logical way is to change the **row height** to **at least**, as this would allow to automatically fit content.

If you want to change the cell width this could be a problem, as the table could become wider than the containing page. While page size is not an issue in Excel, InDesign is built around print, so you need to keep your content inside the page.